# Use approval with deployment to azure app service from azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice, azure-yaml-pipelines

We are creating a yaml pipeline that uses the AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 task to deploy the code to an app service.

Before, we deployed to our own virtual machines, and we could register the virtual machine as an environment in azure devops, and register a deployment agent as a resource to it. Then we could add an approval gate to the environment to make sure approval is required to be able to deploy to the environment.

Now with azure app services, there doesn't seem to be a way to register the app service as an environment, so we have not Environment to set the approval gate on.

How can we add an approval to the deployment of our app? I find it hard to believe it is not possible for app services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered it's possible to add approvals to a service connection in the same way you can with environments. This allows me to add a gate to my deployment!